# html template literal - hide outer div based on inner div iterator property (lit-html)

Tags: html, angular2-template, lit-element, lit-html

I have a collection like this

```
const CollectionItems = {
 [
   "samsung":{
              "battery":"2200mAh",
              "series":"S",
              "region":"inside",
              "instock":"Y",
              "open-issues":4,
              "shipment-progress":"ontrack"
            }
],
[
   "apple":{
              "battery":"2800mAh",
              "series":"11",
              "region":"outside",
              "instock":"Y",
              "open-issues":2,
              "shipment-progress":"ontrack"
            }
],
[
   "Oppo":{
              "battery":"3300mAh",
              "series":"E",
              "region":"inside",
              "instock":"Y",
              "open-issues":7,
              "shipment-progress":"delayed"
            }
],
[
   "Nokia":{
              "battery":"2300mAh",
              "series":"N",
              "region":"inside",
              "instock":"N",
              "open-issues":5,
              "shipment-progress":"delayed"            
            }
],
[
   "OnePlus":{
              "battery":"3800mAh",
              "series":"6",
              "region":"outside",
              "instock":"Y",
              "open-issues":3,
              "shipment-progress":"ontrack"
            }
]
}
```

Now, I am trying to iterate through this collection using lit-html's repeat directive (which is equivalent to ngFor) and I would like to hide all items that fall into 'inside' region. I have a class-level variable 'this.isInSideRegion' whose default value is false and in the collection if I come across an inside region item I am setting this to true.

```
return repeat(Object.entries(CollectionItems), (p) => p[0], (p) => {
      return html`
        <div class ='card' ?hidden = ${this.isInSideRegion === true }> <!-- hide this whole div if 'region' is inside -->
          <label>p[0]</label>
          <div class="container">
          ${p[1].map((l)=> html`
          ${l.region !== 'inside' ? html`
          <span>${l.openIssues}</span>
          <span>${l.instock}</span>
          `: this.isInSideRegion = true }
          `)}
          </div>
        </div>
        `;
    });
```

But for me in the case of an inside region, I am still getting a template. eg: for samsung, I am getting template as

```
samsung
false
```

Where as my expectation is an empty template

Comment: why not use `?hidden = p.region === 'inside'`

Answer (score 0):

"hidden" property doesn't mean anything in lit-html. "hidden" directive is angular specific. You should be using "styleMap" or "classMap" directive for lit-html to add conditional styling. Please refer to their styling [documentation](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/styling-templates) for more details.